# Jquery Empty validation for text box

Tags: jquery, validation

I've a text box in a form,when a user submits the form,it should check whether the user has filled it,other validation would be have some min characters,he has to fill.

here is my code,which is not validating

```
$('.textboxid').bind("submit", function() {
  if($(this).val() == "") {
    jQuery.error('Fill this field');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not validating because, you are binding `submit` event on a textbox. You should use forms to do that.

Apart from sudhir's answer, which will work fine. To provide an alternative to it. You can use regex validations too.

An Nice example, which adds errors messages after the textbox as well.

```
$("#yourFormId").submit(function() {
    var inputVal= $("#yourTextBoxId").val();
    var characterReg = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})$/;
    if(!characterReg.test(inputVal)) {
        $("#yourTextBoxId").after('<span class="error">Maximum 8 characters.</span>');
    }
});
```

Comment: :It is posting the form,it is not validating

Comment: @user1263374, post you html on the question. Lets see

Comment: :I fixed it but if i input 5 character's also,it is submitting the form.

Comment: @user1263374, if you want to limit the characters, change the `{1,}` part to any number you want like `{5,10}` to accept 5 as minimum and 10 as maximum.

Comment: :Say,i've an error,again,if i fill wrongly,it is displaying two error.How to remove first error

Comment: @user1263374, I think you are mixing question here. Which error are you talking about?

Comment: :If i use .fadeto(),it is taking the text box bcoz,we've mentioned text box class.i want text box to stay but mesage to vanish

Comment: :i,m using your same code,just thing,when user submit forms twice,it print errors two times.

Comment: :For eg:Say,i've span tag in form,how to dynamically show the error in span tag so here i can used fadeout() too.Tell me,how to do this alone.

Comment: !Starx:  $("#yourFormId").submit(function() {
            var inputVal= $("#yourTextBoxId").val();
            var characterReg = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,})$/;
            if(!characterReg.test(inputVal)) {
                $("#e").data('Maximum 8 characters.').fadeTo(1000);
            }
        });
        
        
        <span id='e'></span>

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
$("#yourFormId").submit(function() {
  var textVal = $("#yourTextBoxId").val();
  if(textVal == "") {
    alert('Fill this field');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $(function () {

             var textVal = $("#yourTextBoxId").val();
             if (textVal == "") {
                 $("#error").fadeIn(500).show();

             } });
```

add the div where the error message should appear.

```
 <div id="error">Enter Value...</div>
```